# Конструктор классов

Tags: c#, .net

Например есть такой класс(к примеру)

```
 public class Person
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            Age = 10;
            Name = "Nick";
        }
    }
```

Вот мне что интересно я когда начал изучать программирование мне говорили что для конструктора класса не используется понятие **возвращаемый тип**,по той причине что конструктор работает всякий раз когда создается объект этого класса и поскольку тип объекта эта тип класса тогда нету смысла для конструктора написать тип возвращаемого значения(или я что не так понял?),и мне это не так и интересовал и я не стал искать ответов.
Но не давно начал изучать книгу Рихтера(CLR via C#) и при просмотре `IL` кода увидел вот такое

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
    instance void  .ctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  nop
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Program::.ctor
```

Если я не ошибаюсь эта *"instance void"*  часть значит что у конструктора привязан возвращаемый тип `void`.
Как это объяснить?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Возвращаемый тип `void`, это разве не отсутсвие возвращаемого значения? Конструктор в .NET вызывается как метод класса. В вашем примере выше вызывается базовый конструктор типа System.Object:

```
ldarg.0
```

Загружается первый аргумент метода в стек. Все нестатические методы неявно имеют первый параметр - указатель на экземпляр объекта

```
call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
```

Вызывает контруктор System.Object на экземпляре вашего класса. Как аргумент передан указатель на экземпляр вашего класса.

Comment: `System.Object` вызывается всякий раз когда исползуется класс, и не имеет значение какой ,поскольку он базовый для всех

Comment: *это разве не отсутсвие возвращаемого значения?* да это так но мы в резултате работы конструктора получаем инициaлизированный екземпляр самого класса,а это значит что он все таки значение возврашает(и это екземпляр класса),а у екземпляра тип есть и он определен но почему в `IL` коде переписивается как `void`

Comment: @VardanVardanyan, возвращаемое значение это не более чем абстракция высокоуровневых языков, которую Вы пытаетесь натянуть на язык более низкого уровня. Конструктор ничего не возвращает, и `void` этому не противоречит.

Comment: @VardanVardanyan конструктор ничего не возвращает хотя бы потому, что на момент его вызова, экземпляр объекта уже находится в памяти. Это в C# коде выглядит так, как будто он что то возвращает. В IL сначала просто выделяется память под объект (размер памяти заранее известен для каждого объекта). Вот здесь и создается экземпляр. А потом контруктор вызывается на нем.

Answer (score 2):

Void это не тип, это указатель на то, что в результате работы метода не следует  ждать значения и пытаться его куда-то записать. По сути, конструктор - тот же метод, что и любой другой. Он ничего не возвращает, его отработка происходит при создании объекта этого типа. Сначала создаются поля объекта или, как еще их называют, переменные типа, затем выполняется конструктор.

Comment: * Сначала создаются поля объекта * конструктор не создает поля а просто инициализирует их,резултате работы конструктора получаем инициализированный екземпляр самого класса,то есть он возвращает готвый объект определенного типа

Comment: @VardanVardanyan  Вы прочтите сначала внимательно ответ, прежде чем назвать ответ бесполезным. Я не писал, о том, что конструктор создает поля. Я писал, что сначала создаются поля,т.е. переменные определенного типа, которые будут принадлежать этому объекту, а затем вызывается конструктор. И еще, конструктор не обязан ничего инициализировать, а инициализация может происходить и при создании полей. Кроме того, конструктор ничего не возвращает. А теперь будьте столь любезны, снимите необоснованный дизлайк с моего ответа.

Comment: мой вам совет ишите и читайте ,напишите код и тестируйте его что бы вам понятнее было как работает **Конструктор класса** и чем занимается при вызове,буду любезным и скажу вы чуть чуть перебаршили своими знаниямы ,сначала читайте вопрос поймите что требуется а потом уже напишите ответ,вопрос было не о **полях или методах или каких то еще членов класс**, а именно *возвращаемого значения конструктора*

Comment: О возвращаемом значение конструктора я вам написал, что void это не тип, и конструктор ничего не возвращает, и если вы этого не понимаете, и продолжает утверждать, что конструктор  возвращает вам какой-то готовый объект, то видимо пытаться поддерживать разговор с вами бесполезно. Не путайте синтаксис языка C# с тем, как объекты создаются.

Comment: спасибо вам за труды божьих